# Strange GCC optimisation bug

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I'm writing a fairly large application containing many different modules. I've always been programming with the GCC debugging info turned on and all optimisations turned off, for obvious reasons of debugging. Now I've decided that it's time for a release and I've set GCC to optimise to the best of it's abilities (-O3). And this is when the strangest of bugs appeared. Take the following code:

```
void SomeClass::setValue(int i) { this->iValue = i; }
int  SomeClass::getValue() const { return this->iValue; }
```

Now without optimisations, these work perfectly. **With optimisations,** the value of `SomeClass.iValue` **is not modified** in the `setValue()` method. In fact, the output of the following:

```
cout << x.getValue();
x.setValue(5);
cout << x.getValue();
```

returns

```
0
0
```

when the `iValue` is intialised in the class to 0.

Now the strange part: if I insert the following code into `setValue()`:

```
void SomeClass::setValue(int i) { cout << "Narf"; this->iValue = i; }
```

the code works!

Can someone please explain to me what is going on?

Comment: `void SomeClass::getValue() const ` - why the `void` and `const` ? should be `int` ?

Comment: Is `iValue` a static member? It looks like one by the way you are using it in those functions.

Comment: when you clams compiler bug then you should also specify compiler version.

Comment: Without seeing an actual complete example, it's hard to give any specific advice here.

Comment: You should turn your compiler warnings up.

Comment: I corrected those typos (they were indeed typos, sorry). Also, you're not going to see any actual code here since the project is HUGE (and top secret :)). However, I can say with certitude that I nrrowed it down to these very instructions.

Comment: If you aren't going to post any actual code, then don't expect an actual answer.  You're going to get a guess at best.  The few lines you put here are certainly not enough to reproduce the problem, let alone diagnose it.

Comment: Compiler bugs these days are really rare, and even more rare in such simple situations. Most things you see with -O3 is that it is much more sensitive to UB you invoke.

Answer (score 2):

did you try checking `cout<<x.iValue;` ? perhaps the problem is in `SomeClass::getValue();` for example, it returning `void` or being `const` ? :)

also, just an idea, the optimisation might happen in cout not your actual code as hinted by `cout << "Narf";`

Comment: `getValue()` is a getter, so it's just fine as a const member function. And the return type was most likely mistyped, as the compiler would have prevented a void function from returning an int.

Comment: 1+, idk, maybe the optimiser does some magic to consts ? my point being he doesnt check if the value is changed, only output of a function, this might help identify where the bug is, cause the code in the question probably has little to do with the actual code..

Comment: A const member function only prevents an object from being modified (or invoking other non-cost member functions) in those member function calls. The setter function isn't const, and would change the object's state just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code is not exactly correct. Getter function should return int instead of void. I think you just typed it incorrectly here, because gcc will not let you compile that (std::cout has no overloaded operator << for type void). What is more, `SomeClass.i_value` doesn't compile either. Did you mean `this->i_value` or just `i_value`?

Comment: Yeah it's into, not void, that's a typo. As is SomeClass instead of this->. I'm just really tired, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, -O3 is not the best optimization flag, especially for large projects. It is the strongest one, but it may end even in segfaults (i.e. by inlining functions that are not explicitly inlined). Sometimes it may even cause the resulting binary to be larger that -O2. The best flags imho are -O2 or even -Os.

Comment: @Garrappachc: We are not using gcc 2.96 anymore, -O3 is as safe as -O2, it just tends to reveal UB much more often.